# The below code causing an infinite loop eventhough i didn't use head node in the while loop

Tags: python, singly-linked-list

After curr_node1 and curr_node2 becomes null while loop should have been terminated but instead it is causing an infinite loop. What is the reason of this can someone please explain it to me in simple words as I am a newbie.

```
class Node1:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data=data
        self.next=None



class Node2:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data=data
        self.next=None

def merge_sorted_ll(list1,list2):
    head=list1
    head.next=list2
    head=head.next
    curr_node1=list1
    curr_node2=list2
    while curr_node1 and curr_node2:
        curr_node1=curr_node1.next
        curr_node2=curr_node2.next
        head.next=curr_node1
        head.next.next=curr_node2
        head=head.next.next
    return head


list2=Node2(10)
list2.next=Node2(21)
list2.next.next=Node2(31)

list1=Node1(10)
list1.next=Node1(20)
list1.next.next=Node1(30)

merge_sorted_ll(list1,list2)
```

I want to merge two sorted linkedlist and please don't give me a corrected version of code. I know the logic is wrong but I just wanted to know why my code causing an infinite loop.

Comment: Are you changing the code? Is this the code? Or are more changes coming?

Answer (score 1):

It may help to draw the linked lists on paper and draw each change that the code brings to them.

When your function starts, the names `list1` and `list2` are referencing the structures below. I also include the result of `head=list1`:

```
list1   head
┌─┴───────┴──┐      ┌────────────┐      ┌────────────┐
│ data: 10   │      │ data: 20   │      │ data: 30   │
│ next: ────────────┤ next: ────────────┤ next: None │
└────────────┘      └────────────┘      └────────────┘

list2
┌─┴──────────┐      ┌────────────┐      ┌────────────┐
│ data: 10   │      │ data: 21   │      │ data: 31   │
│ next: ────────────┤ next: ────────────┤ next: None │
└────────────┘      └────────────┘      └────────────┘
```

Then the first problem is introduced, because `head.next=list2` overwrites the original `next` reference, and so we lose the rest of the first list:

```
list1   head        (no more reference to this)
┌─┴───────┴──┐      ┌────────────┐      ┌────────────┐
│ data: 10   │      │ data: 20   │      │ data: 30   │
│ next: ─┐   │      │ next: ────────────┤ next: None │
└────────│───┘      └────────────┘      └────────────┘
         │
list2    │
┌─┴──────┴───┐      ┌────────────┐      ┌────────────┐
│ data: 10   │      │ data: 21   │      │ data: 31   │
│ next: ────────────┤ next: ────────────┤ next: None │
└────────────┘      └────────────┘      └────────────┘
```

The next three assignments to names `head`, `curr_node1` and `curr_node2` lead to this (I omit the nodes to which we lost any reference):

```
list1   curr_node1
┌─┴───────┴──┐
│ data: 10   │
│ next: ─┐   │
└────────│───┘
         │
list2    │
┌─┴──────┴───┐      ┌────────────┐      ┌────────────┐
│ data: 10   │      │ data: 21   │      │ data: 31   │
│ next: ────────────┤ next: ────────────┤ next: None │
└─┬───────┬──┘      └────────────┘      └────────────┘
head    curr_node2
```

Now the loop starts. Let's look at each iteration...

#### Iteration 1

The loop enters, and `curr_node1` and `curr_node2` move one step along their `next` links:

```
list1   
┌─┴──────────┐
│ data: 10   │
│ next: ─┐   │
└────────│───┘
         │
list2    │
┌─┴──────┴───┐      ┌────────────┐      ┌────────────┐
│ data: 10   │      │ data: 21   │      │ data: 31   │
│ next: ────────────┤ next: ────────────┤ next: None │
└─┬───────┬──┘      └───┬────────┘      └────────────┘
head    curr_node1    curr_node2
```

Now the next problem occurs: the assignment `head.next=curr_node1` will create a cycle, because `head` and `curr_node1` reference the same node:

```
list1   
┌─┴──────────┐
│ data: 10   │
│ next: ─┐   │
└────────│───┘
         │
list2    │ ┌───┐
┌─┴──────┴─┴─┐ │    ┌────────────┐      ┌────────────┐
│ data: 10   │ │    │ data: 21   │      │ data: 31   │
│ next: ───────┘    │ next: ────────────┤ next: None │
└─┬───────┬──┘      └───┬────────┘      └────────────┘
head    curr_node1    curr_node2
```

As a consequence, `head.next.next` is the same as just `head`. With `head.next.next=curr_node2` the link is restored again:

```
list1   
┌─┴──────────┐
│ data: 10   │
│ next: ─┐   │
└────────│───┘
         │
list2    │
┌─┴──────┴───┐      ┌────────────┐      ┌────────────┐
│ data: 10   │      │ data: 21   │      │ data: 31   │
│ next: ────────────┤ next: ────────────┤ next: None │
└─┬───────┬──┘      └───┬────────┘      └────────────┘
head    curr_node1    curr_node2
```

With `head=head.next.next` we get:

```
list1   
┌─┴──────────┐
│ data: 10   │
│ next: ─┐   │
└────────│───┘
         │
list2    │
┌─┴──────┴───┐      ┌────────────┐      ┌────────────┐
│ data: 10   │      │ data: 21   │      │ data: 31   │
│ next: ────────────┤ next: ────────────┤ next: None │
└────────┬───┘      └───────┬────┘      └────┬───────┘
   curr_node1         curr_node2           head
```

#### Iteration 2

The two `curr` references are moved one step again, and so we get:

```
list1   
┌─┴──────────┐
│ data: 10   │
│ next: ─┐   │
└────────│───┘
         │
list2    │
┌─┴──────┴───┐      ┌────────────┐      ┌────────────┐
│ data: 10   │      │ data: 21   │      │ data: 31   │
│ next: ────────────┤ next: ────────────┤ next: None │
└────────────┘      └──────┬─────┘      └──┬─────┬───┘
                     curr_node1      curr_node2 head
```

Now `head.next=curr_node1` will create a greater cycle:

```
list1   
┌─┴──────────┐
│ data: 10   │
│ next: ─┐   │
└────────│───┘
         │
list2    │                   ┌─────────────────────┐
┌─┴──────┴───┐      ┌────────┴───┐      ┌──────────│─┐
│ data: 10   │      │ data: 21   │      │ data: 31 │ │
│ next: ────────────┤ next: ────────────┤ next: ───┘ │
└────────────┘      └──────┬─────┘      └──┬─────┬───┘
                     curr_node1      curr_node2 head
```

And the next `head.next.next=curr_node2` assignment will do nothing, because the references at both sides of the `=` are already equal. Also `head=head.next.next` will not accomplish anything for the same reason.

#### Iteration 3

This iteration starts with a state where the list has a cycle with size 2, and so the first two assignments will swap the two `cur` references:

```
list1   
┌─┴──────────┐
│ data: 10   │
│ next: ─┐   │
└────────│───┘
         │
list2    │                   ┌─────────────────────┐
┌─┴──────┴───┐      ┌────────┴───┐      ┌──────────│─┐
│ data: 10   │      │ data: 21   │      │ data: 31 │ │
│ next: ────────────┤ next: ────────────┤ next: ───┘ │
└────────────┘      └──────┬─────┘      └──┬─────┬───┘
                     curr_node2      curr_node1 head
```

`head.next=curr1` will create the self-reference again, and `head.next.next=curr_node2` will revert that change. `head=head.next.next` will not accomplish anything: the structure of the linked list at the end of this iteration is the same as when the iteration started.

Only the two `cur` references got swapped. The fourth iteration will do the opposite swap, ...etc, and so we have an infinite loop.

Comment: Nice explanation. I finally got it, Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop, `while curr_node1 and curr_node2`, you don't have an exit condition. Right now, the while loop is checking to see if those two objects exist, which they do, so it will always run in a loop. You need to have something to break out of that loop, either by making the conditional false or including a `break` statement somewhere.

Comment: I don't think that's the reason. While loop will run until curr_node1 and curr_node2 becomes null.  If I remove  head=head.next.next  then it doesn't cause an infinite loop but why I don't know.